# Can create a function that calls Debug.Log

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3d C# can i create a function that calls Debug.Log such as this:

```
 void p(string p)
 {
    Debug.Log
    (p);
 }
```

that would work with int, string, Vector3, GameObject ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) can do this already. It takes `object` and `Object` as parameter.These are the function prototypes for [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html):

```
public static void Log(object message);
public static void Log(object message, Object context);
```

You can do this in two ways:

**1**.Use `object` and `Object` as parameter.

```
void p(object message)
{
    Debug.Log(message);
}

void p(object message, Object context)
{
    Debug.Log(message, context);
}
```

**Usage**:

with one parameter

```
p("Test");
p(50);
p(50.5f);
p(false);
```

with multiple parameter

```
p(false, new Object());
```

**2**.Use generics:

```
void p<T1>(T1 message)
{
    Debug.Log(message);
}

void p<T1, T2>(T1 message, T2 context)
{
    Debug.Log(message, context as Object);
}
```

**Usage**:

with one parameter

```
p<string>("Test");
p<int>(50);
p<float>(50.5f);
p<bool>(false);
```

with multiple parameter

```
p<bool,Object>(false, new Object());
```

I would go with the first method as that is easier and faster to type.